# mat-select was not working fine in Angular

Tags: angular

[image]

[image]

app.component.html:

```
<div class="col-12 p-0">
            <mat-paginator class="paginator col-12" (page)="pageEvent = 
                   getServerData($event)"
                           [length]="totalRecords"
                           [pageSize]="search.size"
                           [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons> 
             </mat-paginator>

</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-select-panel-wrap {
 flex-basis: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 40px !important;
 padding-left: 12px !important;
 }
```

when i am selecting 10,20,50 the mat-select was working fine and even after selecting 100 its displays 100 rows.But when the select value was on 100 and i try to select the mat-select  was going above as shown in the image.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-paginator-jhx2jf?file=app/table-pagination-example.ts

Thanks.

Comment: please provide [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-paginator?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.html) code sample to let us debug

Comment: @AlexYu, I have added stackblitz. please have a look

Comment: remove or comment `padding-bottom: 40px !important;` and check may be it will solve your problem

Comment: No, it doesn't work @KiranMistry

Comment: @vidya please check my post/answer below

Comment: Please Vote Up so other developer will find easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your issue. The problem is `cdk-overlay-pane` is applying their own CSS, so you need to add CSS for that.

Add styling code in `Style.css`:

```
.cdk-overlay-pane{
  min-width: 56px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: 20.6875px;
  left: 133.391px;
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;  // set 0px for X and Y
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much..

Comment: Please refrain from adding greetings and other chatty material into Stack Overflow posts. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom. Thank you!